# Why piping Python logger output to tail or lnav messes the output line endings?

Tags: python, linux, tail

I have a long-running python program which produces a lot of logs. I want to format the logs using an external tool (lnav, multitail, ...), mainly to get colored logs without changing my code (for example, get red on `[ERROR]`, green on `[INFO]` etc). The problem is that piping the python program to tail, lnav, or anything else, messes up the line endings. Here is an example of how the log normally looks like:

```
[INFO]: Started
[INFO]: Data 0 captured
[ERROR]: Connection down
```

And this is how it looks like when piped to tail, lnav, etc.

```
[INFO]: Started
                 [INFO]: Data 0 captured  [ERROR]: Connection down
```

Is it caused by piping? How can I get it to respect the line endings?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself with the same problem, and after much experimentation, here's what works for me:

1. In your python logger, set up a logging format, and **make sure to use sys.stdout as the stream**

```py
import sys
import logging

FORMAT = '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(name)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, stream=sys.stdout)
```

2. [optional] To make the most out of lnav, you'll want to teach it how to interpret the log format you're using.

   [Here's the lnav log parser I use with the format string above.](https://gist.github.com/raphaelcastaneda/d47d1a26183c1a5a892f8f5e1c22a8d6)